# New user creation option not available in SSMS sql server 2106 , how to enable?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

i need to create New user through SSMS in SQL server 2016

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper rights in this db?

Comment: If you're not using the latest version of SSMS, [go get it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). If you are, [run a repair](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-repair-sql-server-management-studio).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your installation of SSMS is messed up. Try using SSMS on a different machine and see if you get the same behaviour there.

If it is SSMS that is messed up, then I suggest you just install the most recent version of SSMS and work with that. Hopefully that will sort things out for you.

(I initially thought that you might not have *permissions* to create a user, but I tried that and SSMS still gave me a "new user" option, but at a later stage I would get an error that I don't have permissions to create a user.)

You can of course always use the `CREATE USER` command from a query window.